# Dependencies not being installed in Openshift [Flask]

Tags: python, flask, dependencies, openshift, google-api-python-client

I am deploying my flask project into Openshift, however it seems that Openshift is not installing the dependencies provided in the setup.py file.

This is my code:

```
setup(
  ...
  install_requires=['Flask==0.10.1','SQLAlchemy==0.9.8','flask-
  login==0.2.7','flask-pymongo-0.4.1','httplib2-0.9.2', 'oauth2client-2.2.0',
 'pyasn1-modules-0.0.8', 'rsa-3.4.2','google-api-python-client-1.5.1'  
 ,'simplejson-3.8.2', 'uritemplate-0.6'],

)
```

however these are the packages installed on Openshift

```
Babel==0.9.6
docutils==0.11
Extractor==0.6
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.2.7
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.6
MarkupSafe==0.11
MySQL-python==1.2.3
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.7.1
projectmanager==1.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
Pygments==1.5
scipy==0.12.1
simplejson==3.2.0
six==1.7.3
Sphinx==1.1.3
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
virtualenv==13.1.0
Werkzeug==0.8.3
wheel==0.24.0
```

Could someone tell me why is this happening and how can I work this out.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you switched from `library==version` to `library-version` part way through your requirements list.

Try:

```
setup(
  ...
  install_requires=[
    'Flask==0.10.1','SQLAlchemy==0.9.8','flask-login==0.2.7',
    'flask-pymongo==0.4.1','httplib2==-0.9.2', 'oauth2client==-2.2.0',
    'pyasn1-modules==-0.0.8', 'rsa==-3.4.2','google-api-python-client==-1.5.1',
    'simplejson==-3.8.2', 'uritemplate==-0.6'
  ],
)
```